# aria labelledby on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I am working on making my website accessible and have added aria-labelledby for controls.

same works on Chrome properly, however does not seem to work on IE 11.

Is there a setting that can make it work ? OR is there an alternative of aria-labelledby for Internet Explorer.

Any help is highly appreciated... Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by not working? We cannot understand the issue properly if you just say it is not working. I suggest you to provide any sample code to reproduce the issue. Also inform us, which output you are getting and what is the expected output? We will try to check the issue and try to provide you suggestions for it.

Comment: `aria-labelledby` works great for IE.  i use it all the time.  can you post your code?  what screen reader are you using?

Answer (score 0):

aria-labelledby should work fine on IE11.
If you post some markup I'll have a look for you and try to figure out why it's not working.